# How to find bugs that cause unclean seed of headers 

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session

I don't know if I missed something while developing my application using Zend_Framwork, but here's my problem, I can't see any cookies, when I run my application on host server, but on my WAMP server everything worked well ..

I stock on sessions, user information to use it later, so on host server I can't login..

I use Zend_Auth and Zend_Acl, here's my bootstrap

```
$modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader ( array ('basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH, 'namespace' => '', 'resourceTypes' => array ('form' => array ('path' => 'forms/', 'namespace' => 'Form_' ) ) ) );

    $this->_acl = new Application_Plugin_Acl ();
    $this->_auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance ();
```

I also use Zend_Auth getStorage()->write('...') to write infos in sessions.
And I have nothing related to sessions on my application.ini

Comment: What is the session.save_path? Does the webserver process have permissions to write there?

Comment: I tried 2 path, the default one and when I added in my application.ini this resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session", same result in both cases :/

Comment: And you're sure that the web-server process has permissions to write into the `data/session` directory? I usually have to explicitly set those permissions (0755; sometimes - to my shame - even 0777 for testing) on that directory.

Comment: Hi, for the default path the process have the permission to write, but for the data/session, I'm not sure how to set those permissions, for the session directory I already set it to 0777, but not for data and the whole tree ..

Comment: OK, if you've tried 0777 and still no dice, then it's probably not the directory permissions issue I was targeting. Must be something else. ;-(

Answer (score 1):

So, it is WORKING on WAMP but, not on host servers. I presume you mean to say your VPS or dedicated server or say any cloud.

`Zend_Auth` uses `$_SESSION` and it has many functions operating on it. For instance, $_SESSION['Zend_Auth']['storage'] will give you information about what is in your `hasIdentity()` checking stuff.

So, what you should do is, get this pasted somewhere near the code and run it, just for your reference

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Also, you can't see Cookies because they are session cookies which has 1 reference on client machine and rest all are on file system (if not configured) of the server.

Hope that helps.

Questions?

Comment: I tried to print the $_Session on my VPS, and it was null, nothing on it, what I mean by I can't see cookies, when I run it in Wamp I see somthing like PHPSESSID containing a Hash, while on my VPS it got nothing "this site Has no cookies".

Comment: Excellent. and it does not work on your VPS either... which means, your VPS does not set cookies. Checking PHP.ini file.